# Clients Complaining for slow speed of my osCommerce Website

Tags: php, performance

My Clients are Complaining for slow speed of my osCommerce Website.. I dont have the basic idea to check out for the speed down of my website.. What could be the issue in this matter?

Could Anybody guide me regarding this...

Comment: sometimes clients use complaining as a negotiation tool. first check if what they are saying is correct and can  be replicated for a particular browser and context.

Comment: all the answers are just guessing. An url could help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) plugin for firefox, it will tell you where it goes 'wrong'

Answer (score 2):

Take [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/1843/)/[YSlow](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/5369/) or something similar to find out what takes so long.
Possible improvements:

1. Google how to speed up osCommerce in general. (cache, etc.)
2. If possible speed up you PHP installation by using a php byte code cache (e.g.: [eAccelerator](http://eaccelerator.net/))
3. If possible tweak you web server. For Apache interesting options could be [mod_deflate](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_deflate.html) (decreases size of transfered data) and setting the headers for caching CSS/JavaScript via [mod_expires](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_expires.html) (more strict caching for assets)

If you are only able to do 1. on the site is still to slow, consider to use a more powerful web hosting or a eCommerce solutions that performs better.

Answer (score 2):

A dedicated machine, some extra RAM, upgrading hardware is the fastest solution... not the cheapest of course.

Comment: It might, but analysing the code/db for any performance issues first is better than simply throwing hardware at the problem

Comment: true. it also take a while longer to optimize a website with lot of code and not knowing where the problem is. I would be curious if the performance of the website decreased in time or this is the first time the clients notice slowness. Maybe this could point to a particular problem.

Answer (score 1):

Change your hosting provider.

Comment: Are u Serious? Is that the only reason?

Comment: it would make sense for very specific problems, like when your clients are from Europe and your hosting is in the US. In this case changing your provider may help.

Comment: You are right, I was not talking about the server's location, but the server itself. I don't think the problem is with OsCommerce or its implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Use a profiler (Firebug has one), and you'll see what takes so long to load.

Comment: ok i got the profiler activated how should i examine the website now?

Answer (score 1):

Corrupted indexes, lack of correct indexes, overall slow performance on your hosting.

First step, run optimize on ALL tables (this might take a long time, if your worried about it use ANALYZE instead):

```
OPTIMIZE TABLE table_name
```

That would rule out any maintenance issues you might having.